# How to mimic HTML Post with Php

Tags: php, post

I want to mimic the html form post without any response in php.

In other words;

1) html form >> 2) validation with PHP >> 3) Bank's 3D secure URL check page

I can do it with JQUERY as :

-) when html form submitted, jquery validates data and redirects to Bank's page

For cURL or http_build_query; they ping the URL and get the response whereas I want to send the user to the link (I'm not interested in the result of POST request, rather I want to forward the page to the bank's page with post data)

Comment: Any code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try to clarify, I can not understand what you mean. You want to mimic the pushing of the submit button in an HTML form? [Curl](http://se2.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) sounds like the solution, but you say it's not what you want, but I can't understand why.

Comment: I have an html form which user enters credit card info. When user click submit, it submits data to my php file which validates the data. If validation is not OK, php reloads the form but if the validation is OK, I want to submit the form data with payment gateway options to banks page. In banks page, user answers bank's question and if answer is ok, banks redirect user to another page. So when I send the post request to bank, I want to redirect the user to bank's page rather then getting content of bank's page.

Comment: @Smamatti If I submit the html form to bank's page directly, it's working. But I want to validate data with php and then submit (and forward the user) to bank's page.

Answer (score 2):

### DO NOT interfere between the user and their bank.

It can be considered as fraud.
**Every** online banking system has a way to tell you if a transaction was successful or not. That's all you need to know.

Comment: Yes they send the result to a page with results but I have to put variables to html form without encription such as storeID, storeUSER etc. So I dont want that info to be shown in the user's form. I dont try to save card info or anything. So there is nothing which can be called fraud. In basic processing we do it with cURL, but for 3D, user have to be redirected to bank's page and bank redirects it to our site again.

Comment: Look. Every one online shop works without asking user's credit card info. I highly doubt your case is so special that you need it. What is your problem? You can verify order details first, store them in the session and then let a user communicate with the bank. What is your problem that cannot be solved with REGULAR methods?

Comment: Actually your writing style is not good. If I need to make fraud, I dont think to ask a question here. The bank provides standard example html which we have to fill userID, terminalID, merchantID, so the user can view this info where he writes credit card info(as it is standard html page). So what we wanted to do is creating a form which only has credit card info sections in the html form and after validating the user data, adding our company specific info to the post and send it to bank. That's it.

Comment: What's wrong with filling userID, terminalID, merchantID? Every bank customer doing that. There is nothing secret in these IDs. What's wrong if someone sees it? These ids are way less secret than credit card info. Do you have at least SSH connection to protect it? BTW, there is no way redirect a user to the bank page with POST method anyway.

Comment: Why do I have to have SSH? User enters his/her info at and SSL secured page. I think where are talking about apples and oranges. Every bank customer does not do that. We have another virtual POS with another bank and we send the info with cURL to the bank after validating user input and show results according to bank's response. But I have asked a different thing here, you are just blaming without asking what we are trying to achieve.

Comment: Well, I meant SSL. So, you have it, at least. Anyway, asking user for their credit card info is extremely bad behavior as nobody can guarantee that you don't store them or don't have your site infected by some trojan software. Anyway, there is no way to do what you are asking for. You CAN'T make a browser to send the POST page.